# Expand Bash variable with forward slash in name

Tags: bash, environment-variables, sh

After something like

```
env "my/test=hi" bash
```

I now have an environment variable set named `my/test`, but various ways I've tried to expand it don't seem to work and produce various weird errors. For example, the straightforward option:

```
$ echo $my/test
/test
```

more clever:

```
$ echo $"my/test"
my/test
```

still no:

```
$ echo ${my/test}
```

(that just returns `\n`)

Running `printenv` I can clearly see the variable is set. How do I reference it so it expands/substitutes in like a "normally" named variable?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. That's not a valid shell variable name. bash [defines a `name`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-name) as:

> A word consisting solely of letters, numbers, and underscores, and beginning with a letter or underscore. Names are used as shell variable and function names. Also referred to as an identifier.

You'll have to parse the output of printenv to get the value.

Comment: Even that (which is to say, parsing printenv) isn't reliable. The shell is legally allowed to delete variables with invalid names from the environment during startup, and some versions do so.

Comment: ...I added a duplicate specifically about that behavior (with an answer citing chapter and verse of the POSIX spec re: the "allowed to do so" assertion) to the list tagged to the question.